# Saving a data using a Loop data in SQL

Tags: php, codeigniter

Hi I have a project and trying to save the data that is being loop. And I am using codeigniter as framework on PHP. And I am not able to save the data on the Loop statement.

Here is my model:

```
$tdl ='';
    $append = 'insert into collateral3 (clientId, resAreatdl, resNumtdl, resValasstdl, resYearasstdl, comAreatdl, comNumtdl, comAssvaltdl, comYearasstdl, agriAreatdl, agriNumtdl, agriAssvaltdl, agriYearasstdl) values ';
    if (array_key_exists('tdl', $info)) {
        foreach($info['tdl'] as $row) {
            if (!empty($row['resAreatdl'])) {
                $tdl .= $append ."('$clientId', upper('{$row['resAreatdl']}'), upper('{$row['resNumtdl']}'), upper('{$row['resAssvaltdl']}'), upper('{$row['resYearasstdl']}'), upper('{$row['comAreatdl']}'), upper('{$row['comNumtdl']}'), upper('{$row['comAssvaltdl']}'), upper('{$row['comYearasstdl']}'), upper('{$row['agriAreatdl']}'), upper('{$row['agriNumtdl']}'), upper('{$row['agriAssvaltdl']}'), upper('{$row['agriYearasstdl']}'))";
            }
            $append =", ";
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

For more than one record use batch insert

```
if (array_key_exists('tdl', $info)) {
    foreach($info['tdl'] as $row) {
     $data[] =  array(
       'clientId' => $clientId ,
       'resAreatdl' => $row['resAreatdl'],
       'resNumtdl' => $row['resNumtdl']
        /* add your all field like this*/
       );
    }
 }
 $this->db->insert_batch('collateral3', $data);
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply Nimisha.

Comment: I have added the the code on my model but I am getting an error 'Undefined property: Romans::$db' and Call to a member function insert_batch() on null..

Comment: Have you load your database library?
`$autoload[‘libraries’] = array(‘database’);`

Comment: Hello Nimisha, what I have in my autoload is : $autoload['libraries'] = array("session","app");  ...i tried to change that to $autoload[‘libraries’] = array(‘database’);  but i gives me database error.  thank you for your reply.